# Saber si usuario ingresa una vocal y si ingresó más de un caracter

Tags: javascript

No logro que funcione el siguiente código. Lo que tengo que lograr es escribir una función que reciba una letra y, si es una vocal, muestre el mensaje “Es vocal”, pero a la vez tengo que verificar si el usuario ingresó un string de más de un caracter y, en ese caso, informarle que no se puede procesar el dato mediante el mensaje "Dato incorrecto".

```
function esVocal(letra) {
    if (letra === 'a' || letra === 'e' || letra === 'i' || letra === 'o' || letra === 'u') {
    console.log('Es vocal')
   } else if (letra.length !== 1) {
   console.log('Dato incorrecto')
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar qué no te funciona exactamente? Yo lo he probado y aparentemente, funciona bien

Comment: Bienvenido a **SOes**! Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida y leer [ask]. Tu código parece correcto, aunque quizá estás esperando un valor de retorno de esa función. Sin un ejemplo de cómo estás usándola, es complicado entender tu problema.

Comment: Hola Lucio, ¿Cuál es el valor que le estás pasando a tu función que hace que la misma no te funcione?

Comment: Puedes también usar una regex `^[aeiou]$`

Comment: Usar una expresión regular para esto es mucha artillería para matar una mosca. ;)

Comment: Primero podrías validar el tipo y tamaño del dato recibido. Si se superan ambas condiciones: tipo cadena y 1 sólo carácter, entonces podrías validar si es una vocal o no. Piensa en esto como *puertas lógicas*: sólo la combinación correcta será válida. Saludos

Comment: Gracias gente!!! Voy a probar con todo esto que me comentaron, lo de regex todavia no lo manejo bien, y no llegamos a verlo en el curso. Para que tengan en cuenta soy muy principiante en esto de Javascript y SOes!

Comment: Una cosa más: creo que se están olvidando de las marcas diacríticas (los acentos, vaya): estas soluciones no funcionarán con á, é, ò, ù

Answer (score 1):

Por lo general utilizo expresión regular. Saludos!

```
function isVowel (vowel) {
      if (typeof vowel === 'string' && vowel.length === 1) {
        return vowel.match(/[aeiou]/) ? console.log('TIene vocal') : console.log('No tiene Vocal')
      } else {
        console.log('Dato incorrecto')
      }
    }
    
    isVowel('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Una pequeña forma de optimizar tu código sería la siguiente

```js
function isVocal(char){
  if(["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(char.toLowerCase())){
    console.log("Vocal!")  
  }else {
    console.log("Not a vocal!")
  }
}

isVocal("a"); //Vocal!
isVocal("j"); //Not a vocal!
isVocal("test"); //Not a vocal!
isVocal(""); //Not a vocal!
```

De esta forma te ahorras escribir tantos `&&` en el primer `if`. Si necesitases gestionar de alguna manera los errores por separado, sería cuestión de añadir un `else if` mas.